# Pointer to standard C operators

Tags: c

I am trying to implement some code that requires pointers to standard C functions. I am currently using a workaround that looks something like this:

```
uint32_t add(uint32_t op1, uint32_t op2) {
    return op1 + op2;
}

sum = (&add) (x, y);
```

I was wondering if there are pointers to standard functions such as `+`, `-`, `&`, etc.?

Comment: Highly doubtful - those all get treated differently at different times by the compiler, so I assume they're not considered a simple "function" per se.

Comment: I changed the title as these are operators, not functions.  Pointers to standard C functions would not be a problem.

Comment: Built-in operators are not functions, neither in C nor in C++. It is not possible to create pointers to them. (Aside from exactly what you are doing above.)

Comment: @EOF: with very few exceptions, standard library functions must be implemented as functions. They may *also* be implemented as function-like macros, but the two definitions must behave identically.

Comment: @EOF: See sect 7.1.4: "it is permitted to take the address of a library function even if it is also implemented as a macro."

Comment: @AnT: I'm not sure, IIRC, you can overload the operators by member functions in C++. But I never tried taking their address. C, of course, is a different language and you are completely right.

Answer (score 1):

+,- etc are not functions in C. They are operators. pointer to function is a commonly used feature in C. But pointer to an operator is not possible.

languages like C++ allows you to override an operator. May be this will be useful for you.